# Android Onclick on overlapping layouts

Tags: android, layout, onclick

I created a FrameLayout that fills my entire screen (`red`,`Parent: p`) and then I put a OnClickListener on it.
After that I put another FrameLayout in `p` (`green`).

[image: Android Layout Example]

But now both clicks on the red field **and** on the green field starts the onClick-Method. However, I just want this method to be called when the red area is clicked.

Comment: Layout doesn't cover the Onclick event.. The elements inside Layout does like button,tetview etc.

Comment: it works for me on a FrameLayout

Comment: when you set OnClickListener for parent then it's child can getting OnClickListener...

Comment: the green area is not a child of the red area

Comment: I am telling that the green actually not covering the Red frames onclick. framelayout doesn't cover the onclick event of redone

Comment: I found the solution on my own: I just had to put a second onClickListener on the green area (with an empty onClick-Method) and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to use LinearLayout for this.Set red as backgroundColor for Parent Linear Layout say p.Now pre made the inner layout q and set its visibility gone in first instance.OnClick make it visible.This will works the way you need